# Why Stack widget is taking full height and width in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to give Specific size to my `stack` so tried this:

```
body: Container(
    width: double.infinity,
    height: double.infinity,
    child: Container(
      width: 80,
      height: 80,
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
           // width: 80, then i've to add this size to solve the problem.
           // height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                gradient: LinearGradient(
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    colors: [Colors.green, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)]),
                shape: BoxShape.circle),
          ) 
         ]
        )
       )
      )
```

`Stack` Widget was taking full height and width of screen. So, I want know why, and is there any other way to solve or prevent this issue?

Comment: see https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/layout/constraints

Comment: add alignment property to top Container, for example `alignment: Alignment.topCenter`

Answer (score 1):

**Problem:** When you give your parent `Container` a `width` and `height`, it will pass them as tight constraints (infinite width and height in your case) to its child and will ignore their constraints.

**Solution**: Just remove your parent `Container`.

```dart
body: Container(
  width: 80,
  height: 80,
  child: Stack(
    children: [
      Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          gradient: LinearGradient(
            begin: Alignment.topCenter,
            end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            colors: [Colors.green, Colors.black.withOpacity(0.6)],
          ),
          shape: BoxShape.circle,
        ),
      )
    ],
  ),
)
```

Comment: Ya but if we have to add multiple widget?

Comment: You can add as many widgets as you want but you need to understand how constraints work. In your example, I showed you about the `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

```
       Row(
          children: [
            const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
            // Your Container
          ],
        ),
        
        or 
        
        Column(
          children: [
            const Expanded(child: SizedBox()),
            // Your Container
          ],
        ),
```

Add Expanded To solve